# Is there something wrong with my program? I only seems to get 0.0000 as my answers

Tags: c, branch

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)    
{
    int days, seconds;
    
    printf("Enter the no. of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &days);
    
    seconds = days*36400;
    
    if (days<0)
    {
        printf("Invalid input!");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("It is equal to %.5f seconds", seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: `%.5f` --> `%d`  Explained: `%f` is for floating point but your `seconds` is an `int`. For `int` use `%d`

Comment: You have an integer to print, but you're printing that as a float...

Comment: `36400` ==> `86400` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You declared seconds as an integer, so you should change `%.5f` to `%d`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)
{
  int days, seconds;

  printf("Enter the no. of days: ");
  scanf("%d", &days);
  
  seconds = days*36400;
 
  if (days<0)
    {
      printf("Invalid input!");
    }
  else 
    {
      printf("It is equal to %d seconds", seconds);
    }
  
}
```

Comment: What will `%.5d` do?

Comment: @4386427 decimal digit out of five characters .. Here, changing the `f` to `d` is the solution for the problem. `5` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @hakimo2: `.5` has different meanings with `f` and `d`. With `f` it means to print five digits after the decimal point, even if they are trailing zeros. With `d` it means to print at least five digits, which may cause leading zeros. Leading zeros are rarely actually wanted with integer conversions, so, when fixing `%.5f`, it should be changed to `%d`, not `%.5d`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah, you're right. I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes in your code

1. Before converting days into second you need to check for valid and
   invalid input.
2. You have taken variables in int and printing them as
   floating value.

Yo can use following code to get the output you want

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int days, seconds;

    printf("Enter the no. of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &days);
    if(days<=0){
        printf("Invalid input");
    }else{
        seconds = days * 86400;
        printf("It is equal to: %.5d Seconds", seconds);
    }
}
```